# I am trying to change the input size from 256x256 to 32x32 but as soon as I make changes recieve an error

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

**Error**

raise ValueError("Expected more than 1 value per channel when training, got input size {}".format(size))
ValueError: Expected more than 1 value per channel when training, got input size torch.Size([1, 512, 1, 1])

**Code for Generator (GAN):**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class Block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, down=True, act="relu", use_dropout=False):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, 4, 2, 1, bias=False, padding_mode="reflect")
            if down
            else nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, out_channels, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU() if act == "relu" else nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        )

        self.use_dropout = use_dropout
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.down = down

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        return self.dropout(x) if self.use_dropout else x


class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels=3, features=64):
        super().__init__()
        self.initial_down = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, features, 4, 2, 1, padding_mode="reflect"),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        )
        self.down1 = Block(features, features * 2, down=True, act="leaky", use_dropout=False)
        self.down2 = Block(
            features * 2, features * 4, down=True, act="leaky", use_dropout=False
        )
        self.down3 = Block(
            features * 4, features * 8, down=True, act="leaky", use_dropout=False
        )
        self.down4 = Block(
            features * 8, features * 8, down=True, act="leaky", use_dropout=False
        )
        self.down5 = Block(
            features * 8, features * 8, down=True, act="leaky", use_dropout=False
        )
        self.down6 = Block(
            features * 8, features * 8, down=True, act="leaky", use_dropout=False
        )
        self.bottleneck = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(features * 8, features * 8, 4, 2, 1), nn.ReLU()
        )

        self.up1 = Block(features * 8, features * 8, down=False, act="relu", use_dropout=True)
        self.up2 = Block(
            features * 8 * 2, features * 8, down=False, act="relu", use_dropout=True
        )
        self.up3 = Block(
            features * 8 * 2, features * 8, down=False, act="relu", use_dropout=True
        )
        self.up4 = Block(
            features * 8 * 2, features * 8, down=False, act="relu", use_dropout=False
        )
        self.up5 = Block(
            features * 8 * 2, features * 4, down=False, act="relu", use_dropout=False
        )
        self.up6 = Block(
            features * 4 * 2, features * 2, down=False, act="relu", use_dropout=False
        )
        self.up7 = Block(features * 2 * 2, features, down=False, act="relu", use_dropout=False)
        self.final_up = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(features * 2, in_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.Tanh(),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        d1 = self.initial_down(x)
        d2 = self.down1(d1)
        d3 = self.down2(d2)
        d4 = self.down3(d3)
        d5 = self.down4(d4)
        d6 = self.down5(d5)
        d7 = self.down6(d6)
        bottleneck = self.bottleneck(d7)
        up1 = self.up1(bottleneck)
        up2 = self.up2(torch.cat([up1, d7], 1))
        up3 = self.up3(torch.cat([up2, d6], 1))
        up4 = self.up4(torch.cat([up3, d5], 1))
        up5 = self.up5(torch.cat([up4, d4], 1))
        up6 = self.up6(torch.cat([up5, d3], 1))
        up7 = self.up7(torch.cat([up6, d2], 1))
        return self.final_up(torch.cat([up7, d1], 1))


def test():
    x = torch.randn((1, 3, 32, 32))
    model = Generator(in_channels=3, features=64)
    preds = model(x)
    print(preds.shape)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

**What I Tried**

I am trying to change the input size ->
def test(): x = torch.randn((1,3,32,32)) model = Generator(in_channels=3, features=64) preds = model(x) print(preds.shape)
**from**
def test(): x = torch.randn((1,3,256,256))

I don't know it's an appropriate action to take for decreasing the input size from 256x256 to 32x32.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for calculating the output height or width after a convolutional layer is

(input_size - kernel_size + 2 * padding)/stride + 1

In your code you use a kernel_size of 4, padding of 1, and stride of 2. This means that for each of your down layers (including the initial_down and bottleneck layers), the image height and width get cut in half. In the version of test that you included, your image height and width are 32, so the output shape of down4 will be (1,512,1,1). This can't be put through another convolutional layer since it's just 512 channels of one pixel, and if you apply the formula again, you'd get an image height and width of 0, which is the reason you get the error.

With an image height and width of 256, ie changing x in test to

```
 x = torch.randn((1, 3, 256, 256))
```

it should work, but note that after your bottleneck layer, the shape will be (1, 512, 1, 1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).